# Authentication Protocol in Freeradius

Tags: authentication, protocols, freeradius

I want to setup a radius server for my college of around 2000 students and a hundred faculties. I am familiar with `freeradius`+`MySQL` but never deployed it except for in on my laptop.

1. Which `Authentication protocol` should I Choose if my Considerations are 
    Easy for Users to Connect to `NAS`, Easy to Setup for the Users.(w/o 3rd party softwares).
2. Can I use `WPA2-personal`?
3. Is `Certificates` necessary and if so how can I implement it?
4. Is there any particular `EAP` flavor that is supported by both Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The only protocols which match your requirements are EAP-TLS and EAP-PEAP. They are pretty much universally supported by all supplicants. EAP-PEAP uses username/password as credentials whereas EAP-TLS uses client certificates.
2. No. you should use WPA2-Enterprise.
3. No. Not if you use EAP-PEAP.
4. EAP-PEAP and EAP-TLS are supported by both.

Note: For EAP-PEAP you either need to have the NT-Password hash of the user, the user's password in cleartext, or an Active directory server which you can auth against.

Comment: I have seen you authored freeradius Github page. OMG, Huge Privilage sir..:). And Thanks a Lot..:)

Comment: Well Alan DeKok is the project leader, i'm just a maintainer. But anyway, glad I could help :)